# Should answer's tags be added to the question?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, rollback-wars

I see a conflicting edit in [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array)

branch-prediction tag was explicitly removed from question because it is an answer by itself.

Who is right? Should clues to what the answer is, be removed from tags?